# Get the SoundCloud API track ID from URL for json/ajax in Greasemonkey

Tags: ajax, json, greasemonkey, soundcloud

resolverURLI try to use the SoundCloud API in a Greasemonkey script, but the problem is that the current track ID is not available in the DOM when you browse around.

The only reliable data is the current URL. They offer `api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=` to resolve the track ID from the URL, but Greasemonkey doesn't seem to follow it.

Use the below script and go on a random page. e.g. https://soundcloud.com/soulection/soulection-radio-show-187-w-sango

Activate `url: resolverURL` and nothing will be returned.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SoundCloud track test
// @version      0
// @include      http*soundcloud.com*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// waitUntilExists
(function(e,t){var n={};var r=function(e){if(n[e]){t.clearInterval(n[e]);n[e]=null}};var i="waitUntilExists.found";e.fn.waitUntilExists=function(s,o,u){var a=this.selector;var f=e(a);var l=f.not(function(){return e(this).data(i)});if(s==="remove"){r(a)}else{l.each(s).data(i,true);if(o&&f.length){r(a)}else if(!u){n[a]=t.setInterval(function(){f.waitUntilExists(s,o,true)},500)}}return f}})(jQuery,window)

$(".l-listen-sound").waitUntilExists(function() {

    // some old track id
    var trackIDurl = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=386b66fb8e6e68704b52ab59edcdccc6";
    console.log( "trackIDurl: " + trackIDurl );

    // build the api url from the current browsing url
    var urlE = encodeURIComponent( $(location).attr('href').replace(/\?.+/g, "") ),
        resolverURL = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=' + urlE + '&client_id=386b66fb8e6e68704b52ab59edcdccc6';
    console.log( "resolverURL: " + resolverURL );

    $.ajax({
        url: trackIDurl,
        //url: resolverURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
           alert(result.title);
        }
    });

});
```

I tried several solutions floating around including GM_xmlhttpRequest and unsafeWindow. No luck at all :(

So how could I build the trackIDurl manually?

Comment: Are you really running this on Greasemonkey or some other engine? (GM does not support `@noframes` yet. That's slated for version 2.3.)

Comment: I adapted it from a Tampermonkey script :) But it didn't solve it. OP edited. And hi btw, I know you from my Google "research" :P